# Maven plugin executing another plugin

Tags: maven-2, plugins

I'm trying to create a new plugin to package my latest project.  I'm trying to have this plugin depend on the maven-dependency-plugin to copy all my projects dependencies.

I've added this dependency to my plugin's pom, but I can't get it to execute.

I have this annotation in my plugins main Mojo:

```
@execute goal="org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:copy"
```

I've tried a few other names for the goal, like *dependency:copy* and just *copy* but they all end with a message saying that the required goal was not found in my plugin.  What am I doing wrong?

Secondary to this is where to I provide configuration info for the dependency plugin?

Answer (score 41):

Use the [Maven Mojo executor](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor) by Don Brown of Atlassian fame to run any other arbitrary plugin.

> The Mojo Executor provides a way to to
>   execute other Mojos (plugins) within a
>   Maven 2 plugin, allowing you to easily
>   create Maven 2 plugins that are
>   composed of other plugins.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243686/how-to-programatically-invoke-a-maven-dependency-plugin/5761554#5761554 for an updated version of Mojo Executor for Maven 3.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create your own packaging type? Then you can define your own lifecycle mapping, i.e. bind goals to phases. In this case you can bind the dependency:copy-dependencies goal to your packaging phase and you don't have to wrap the goal into your own Mojo.

See also: [How do I create a new packaging type for Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427722/how-do-i-create-a-new-packaging-type-for-maven)