# How to programatically invoke a maven dependency plugin

Tags: java, maven-plugin, maven-3

I am trying to invoke maven-dependency-plugin programatically. i am using maven 3 version. the problem is that when i invoke it through pluginManager.executeMojo(session, execution), i receive the following error message:

```
[ERROR] **The parameters 'project', 'local', 'remoteRepos',
'reactorProjects' for goal
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:unpack are
missing or invalid**
**org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterException: The parameters 'project',
'local', 'remoteRepos', 'reactorProjects' for goal
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:unpack are missing or
invalid**
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager
        .populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:518)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager
        .getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:471)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager
        .executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:99)
        at com.sap.ldi.qi.osgi.OSGiManifesrMfHandlerMojo
        .invokeMavenDependencyPlugin(OSGiManifesrMfHandlerMojo.java:139)
        at com.sap.ldi.qi.osgi.OSGiManifesrMfHandlerMojo
        .execute(OSGiManifesrMfHandlerMojo.java:100)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager
        .executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor
        .execute(MojoExecutor.java:144)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor
        .execute(MojoExecutor.java:87)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor
        .execute(MojoExecutor.java:79)
-- many lines stripped from stack trace --
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.938s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 22 10:27:42 EET 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/23M
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
com.sap.ldi.qi:osgi-manifest-handler-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:handle
(osgi-manifest-handler plugin) on project com.sap.ldi.demo.calc
.cmd.tests: The parameters 'project', 'local', 'remoteRepos',
'reactorProjects' for goal
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:unpack are missing
or invalid -> [Help 1]
-- stripped rest --
```

As I know, the only required parameter for the unpack goal of maven dependency plugin is artifactItems. I set the plugin configuration by using PluginExecution.setConfiguration() method. It seems that this plugin configuration is not correctly set.
Do you have any idea why this exception is thrown?

Here is the configuration that I am using:

```
<configuration>
  <artifactItems>
    <artifactItem>
      <groupId>com.sap.ldi.demo.calc</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.sap.ldi.demo.calc.cmd</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <overWrite>true</overWrite>
      <outputDirectory>target/demo-calc-stuff</outputDirectory>
      <includes>**/*.*</includes>
    </artifactItem>
  </artifactItems>
</configuration>
```

Thanks

---

One correction from my side. The used Maven version is not Maven 3.0 but Maven 3.0-beta-1. I see that `BuildPluginManager.loadPlugin()` in version 3.0-beta-1 has two args, and the same method in version 3.0 has three. 
I am wondering, does anyone tried to invoke a maven plugin programatically with maven 3.0 or maven 3.0-beta-1. I am still trying to invoke it with maven 3.0-beta-1, but it still returns the same exception as pasted above.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an updated version of Mojo Executor designed for Maven 3:

```
package com.googlecode.boostmavenproject;

import java.util.Collections;
import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession;
import org.apache.maven.model.Plugin;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.descriptor.PluginDescriptor;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.BuildPluginManager;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.descriptor.MojoDescriptor;
import org.codehaus.plexus.configuration.PlexusConfiguration;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3DomUtils;
import org.sonatype.aether.repository.RemoteRepository;

/**
 * Executes an arbitrary mojo using a fluent interface.  This is meant to be executed within the context of a Maven 2
 * mojo.
 *
 * Here is an execution that invokes the dependency plugin:
 * <pre>
 * executeMojo(
 *              plugin(
 *                      groupId("org.apache.maven.plugins"),
 *                      artifactId("maven-dependency-plugin"),
 *                      version("2.0")
 *              ),
 *              goal("copy-dependencies"),
 *              configuration(
 *                      element(name("outputDirectory"), "${project.build.directory}/foo")
 *              ),
 *              executionEnvironment(
 *                      project,
 *                      session,
 *                      pluginManager
 *              )
 *          );
 * </pre>
 * @see http://code.google.com/p/mojo-executor/
 */
public class MojoExecutor
{
    /**
     * Entry point for executing a mojo
     *
     * @param plugin The plugin to execute
     * @param goal The goal to execute
     * @param configuration The execution configuration
     * @param env The execution environment
     * @throws MojoExecutionException If there are any exceptions locating or executing the mojo
     */
    public static void executeMojo(Plugin plugin, String goal, Xpp3Dom configuration,
                                                                 ExecutionEnvironment env) throws MojoExecutionException
    {
        if (configuration == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("configuration may not be null");
        try
        {
            MavenSession session = env.getMavenSession();

            PluginDescriptor pluginDescriptor = env.getPluginManager().loadPlugin(plugin,
                Collections.<RemoteRepository>emptyList(), session.getRepositorySession());
            MojoDescriptor mojo = pluginDescriptor.getMojo(goal);
            if (mojo == null)
            {
                throw new MojoExecutionException("Could not find goal '" + goal + "' in plugin "
                                                                                 + plugin.getGroupId() + ":"
                                                                                 + plugin.getArtifactId() + ":"
                                                                                 + plugin.getVersion());
            }
            configuration = Xpp3DomUtils.mergeXpp3Dom(configuration,
                toXpp3Dom(mojo.getMojoConfiguration()));
            MojoExecution exec = new MojoExecution(mojo, configuration);
            env.getPluginManager().executeMojo(session, exec);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new MojoExecutionException("Unable to execute mojo", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Converts PlexusConfiguration to a Xpp3Dom.
     *
     * @param config the PlexusConfiguration
     * @return the Xpp3Dom representation of the PlexusConfiguration
     */
    private static Xpp3Dom toXpp3Dom(PlexusConfiguration config)
    {
        Xpp3Dom result = new Xpp3Dom(config.getName());
        result.setValue(config.getValue(null));
        for (String name: config.getAttributeNames())
            result.setAttribute(name, config.getAttribute(name));
        for (PlexusConfiguration child: config.getChildren())
            result.addChild(toXpp3Dom(child));
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs the {@link ExecutionEnvironment} instance fluently
     * @param mavenProject The current Maven project
     * @param mavenSession The current Maven session
     * @param pluginManager The Build plugin manager
     * @return The execution environment
     * @throws NullPointerException if mavenProject, mavenSession or pluginManager
     *   are null
     */
    public static ExecutionEnvironment executionEnvironment(MavenProject mavenProject,
                                                                                                                    MavenSession mavenSession,
                                                                                                                    BuildPluginManager pluginManager)
    {
        return new ExecutionEnvironment(mavenProject, mavenSession, pluginManager);
    }

    /**
     * Builds the configuration for the goal using Elements
     * @param elements A list of elements for the configuration section
     * @return The elements transformed into the Maven-native XML format
     */
    public static Xpp3Dom configuration(Element... elements)
    {
        Xpp3Dom dom = new Xpp3Dom("configuration");
        for (Element e: elements)
            dom.addChild(e.toDom());
        return dom;
    }

    /**
     * Defines the plugin without its version
     * @param groupId The group id
     * @param artifactId The artifact id
     * @return The plugin instance
     */
    public static Plugin plugin(String groupId, String artifactId)
    {
        return plugin(groupId, artifactId, null);
    }

    /**
     * Defines a plugin
     * @param groupId The group id
     * @param artifactId The artifact id
     * @param version The plugin version
     * @return The plugin instance
     */
    public static Plugin plugin(String groupId, String artifactId, String version)
    {
        Plugin plugin = new Plugin();
        plugin.setArtifactId(artifactId);
        plugin.setGroupId(groupId);
        plugin.setVersion(version);
        return plugin;
    }

    /**
     * Wraps the group id string in a more readable format
     * @param groupId The value
     * @return The value
     */
    public static String groupId(String groupId)
    {
        return groupId;
    }

    /**
     * Wraps the artifact id string in a more readable format
     * @param artifactId The value
     * @return The value
     */
    public static String artifactId(String artifactId)
    {
        return artifactId;
    }

    /**
     * Wraps the version string in a more readable format
     * @param version The value
     * @return The value
     */
    public static String version(String version)
    {
        return version;
    }

    /**
     * Wraps the goal string in a more readable format
     * @param goal The value
     * @return The value
     */
    public static String goal(String goal)
    {
        return goal;
    }

    /**
     * Wraps the element name string in a more readable format
     * @param name The value
     * @return The value
     */
    public static String name(String name)
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs the element with a textual body
     * @param name The element name
     * @param value The element text value
     * @return The element object
     */
    public static Element element(String name, String value)
    {
        return new Element(name, value);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs the element containg child elements
     * @param name The element name
     * @param elements The child elements
     * @return The Element object
     */
    public static Element element(String name, Element... elements)
    {
        return new Element(name, elements);
    }

    /**
     * Element wrapper class for configuration elements
     */
    public static class Element
    {
        private final Element[] children;
        private final String name;
        private final String text;

        public Element(String name, Element... children)
        {
            this(name, null, children);
        }

        public Element(String name, String text, Element... children)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.text = text;
            this.children = children;
        }

        public Xpp3Dom toDom()
        {
            Xpp3Dom dom = new Xpp3Dom(name);
            if (text != null)
            {
                dom.setValue(text);
            }
            for (Element e: children)
            {
                dom.addChild(e.toDom());
            }
            return dom;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Collects Maven execution information
     */
    public static class ExecutionEnvironment
    {
        private final MavenProject mavenProject;
        private final MavenSession mavenSession;
        private final BuildPluginManager pluginManager;

        public ExecutionEnvironment(MavenProject mavenProject, MavenSession mavenSession,
                                                                BuildPluginManager pluginManager)
        {
            if (mavenProject == null)
                throw new NullPointerException("mavenProject may not be null");
            if (mavenSession == null)
                throw new NullPointerException("mavenSession may not be null");
            if (pluginManager == null)
                throw new NullPointerException("pluginManager may not be null");
            this.mavenProject = mavenProject;
            this.mavenSession = mavenSession;
            this.pluginManager = pluginManager;
        }

        public MavenProject getMavenProject()
        {
            return mavenProject;
        }

        public MavenSession getMavenSession()
        {
            return mavenSession;
        }

        public BuildPluginManager getPluginManager()
        {
            return pluginManager;
        }
    }
}
```

I will attempt to contribute my changes back into the official Mojo Executor plugin.

Comment: I'm the current maintainer of the Mojo Executor library. Gili got in touch with me to let me know about his patched version.This has now been incorporated into the master branch of the project at https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor and has been deployed as version 2.0-SNAPSHOT. If any Maven 3 users could test it and let me know if there are any problems (preferably by filing issues on the GitHub site), that would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the Mojo Executor plugin is great!

Comment: @Gili Hi could you pls tell me how can i initialize these fields ?    MavenProject mavenProject;
         MavenSession mavenSession;
          BuildPluginManager pluginManager;

Answer (score 2):

Folks, I think I get it.
The problem is not in the version of Maven that I am using. It is in the configuration that I am using for invoking maven-dependency-plugin. The unpack goal of maven-dependency-plugin requires the following parameters: **artifactItems**, **local**, **project**, **reactorProjects** and **remoteRepos**. Here is the correct version of the configuration used for invoking the plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <artifactItems>
    <artifactItem>
      <groupId>com.sap.ldi.demo.calc</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.sap.ldi.demo.calc.cmd</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <overWrite>true</overWrite>
      <outputDirectory>target/demo-calc-stuff</outputDirectory>
      <includes>**/*.*</includes>
    </artifactItem>
  </artifactItems>
  <local>${localRepository}</local>
  <project>${project}</project>
  <reactorProjects>${reactorProjects}</reactorProjects>
  <remoteRepos>${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}</remoteRepos>
</configuration>`
```

Comment: The problem is that Maven is telling you that you are not using the complete set of arguments needed for invoking maven-dependency-plugin:unpack, but it is not so easy to find what are the possible values of these tag elements. I had to invoke the plugin through the pom.xml in debug mode in order to find these values and construct the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Maven Plugins are not meant to be invoked programmatically.

They rely on values that are injected by the underlying plexus container.

So either you will have to find out how to inject those values or you will have to rely on the default mechanism.

One thing you can use is the [Maven Invoker](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/). With that, you can programmatically launch maven lifecycles, but they will execute in a separate VM. So if you need to change the model dynamically beforehand, you will need to serialize the model out to a temporary pom.xml and use that with maven invoker. This is heavy stuff, but I have done it successfully some two years ago.

Comment: I thought that BuildPluginManager.executeMojo() is intended for such use cases. I also found the following link, explaining how to invoke maven plugins programatically: http://code.google.com/p/mojo-executor/

Comment: It seems that the implementation used is for maven 2, but Don Brown is using the same idea as explained above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526733/maven-plugin-executing-another-plugin - that is the link to post I am talking about.

Comment: Things apparently seem to have changed a lot since I last did that kind of stuff. The mojo-executor looks very nice.

Comment: It seems that this is the standard way of how to invoke Maven plugins programatically, but there are a lot of changes between maven 2 and maven 3 (in terms of code and refactoring).