# Maven calling goal from java

Tags: java, maven, plugins

We have custom maven plugin which consist of multiple goals like

> @Mojo(name = "BUILD", defaultPhase=LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
>
> @Mojo(name = "BUILDXML", defaultPhase=LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)

now I have created another goal which BUILDVAL below is the code

```
@Mojo(name = "BUILDVAL)
public class Validation extends AbstractMojo {

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        // From here I need to call BUILD and BUILDXML goals.
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

so from above **execute()** method i need to call BUILD and BUILDXML goals. 
I am quite to new Maven plugin development so it might sounds easy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526733/maven-plugin-executing-another-plugin

Comment: Thanks RedLab but if possible could you please provide something at code level :)

Comment: yes, see https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor

Comment: @Redlab I have used maven invoker but not able to find out how to skip the test in setGoal method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338476/maven-invoker-skiping-test-in-goals