# Maven Invoker Skipping Test in Goals

Tags: java, maven, plugins

Below is My code

```
InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
                            request.setPomFile(new File(pom.xml));
                            request.setGoals(Arrays.asList("clean", "install"));
                            Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
                            try {
                                invoker.execute(request);
                            } catch (MavenInvocationException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

when i am calling pom.xml i wanted to skip the test which i am not able to find out.

How to set the skip test in setGoals method.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `skipTests` property to achieve it.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("skipTests", "true");
request.setProperties(properties);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops It was quick fix found the below answer.

```
request.setGoals(Arrays.asList("clean", "install","-Dmaven.test.skip=true"));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a setProperties method https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/apidocs/org/apache/maven/shared/invoker/InvocationRequest.html#setProperties(java.util.Properties)